# Flutter ListView Boundary Splash Color

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to set the splash color that appears when you try to scroll past the end of a ListView?

It defaults to this blue color (at bottom of screen):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ScrollConfiguration(
            behavior: ScrollBehavior(),   // From this behaviour you can change the behaviour 
            child: GlowingOverscrollIndicator(
              axisDirection: AxisDirection.down, 
              color: Colors.yellow,    // You can change your splash color
              child: ListView.builder(
                  .....
              ),
            ),
          );
```

FOr more information you can check this [official docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlowingOverscrollIndicator-class.html)